# Passing dynamic value as a key to Map in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, el

I have a List of keys say 'ListA'. And a map of keys & list say 'MapA'. I need to iterate the 'ListA' & for every key need to get its value from 'MapA'. And those values serve as the model for dataTable.

For this purpose,I'm using h:datatable inside ui:repeat.

```
<ui:repeat var="entry" value="#{bean.sampleDTO.sampleList}"
    varStatus="row">
    <tr>
        <td>#{entry.key}</td>
        <td><h:datatable value="#{bean.map[#{entry.key}]}" var="row">
                <h:column> 
                    // something
                </h:column>
            </h:datatable></td>
    </tr>
</ui:repeat>
```

Please consider the value of datatable:

```
value="#{bean.map[#{entry.key}]}"
```

The issue is that the key is a variable which I get from #{entry.key}. #{bean.map[#{entry.key}]} is an invalid EL expression as 2 # can't  be used.

Thanks,
Tarun Madaan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for the el expression : try this

```
value="#{bean.map[entry.key]}"
```

you dont need to use `#{}` inside `#{}`